# Can't see the admin dropdown in Bitbucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, bitbucket

I am building an app with technologies I'm not familiar with (sails.js, AWS). I am trying to set up CI between Bitbucket and an AWS Ubuntu EC2 instance.

I have created a couple of repositories in Bitbucket and I am the owner of these repositories. The [instructions](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/bitbucket-aws-codedeploy/cloud/installation) I have found say that you need to log in to Bitbucket as an admin and click on the admin link. For some reason, I cannot see an admin link in Bitbucket.

Why is this? Do I need to create an admin account? Why can't the owner see the admin link in Bitbucket?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to bitbucket..

Comment: In what way is tying Bitbucket to AWS off topic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No issue tracker button in bitbucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43194201/no-issue-tracker-button-in-bitbucket)