# No issue tracker button in bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, issue-tracking

I'm trying to set up issue tracking on a bitbucket private repository, but there isn't a button to manage/add issues. In [this](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-issue-tracker-221449750.html) tutorial from atlassian, it clearly shows the issues and wiki buttons, however this must have been before they created pipelines because that button isn't there either. Here's what *my* sidebar looks like:

[image: Sidebar with pipeline but no wiki or issue tracking]

The last blog post I found on their blog relating to issue tracking was about a UI update for managing issues. In the blog post announcing the release of pipelines [here](https://blog.bitbucket.org/2016/10/25/bitbucket-pipelines-now-generally-available/) shows a screenshot that has the same sidebar layout as I have, no issue tracking or wiki button, just pipelines. Did Bitbucket remove issue tracking? Or am I just blind/not looking hard enough? I'm not admin on the repo if that makes a difference, and the team that I'm part of isn't using premium.

Comment: You should go to the settings section of your repository, and enable there the Issue tracking feature.

Comment: The linked tutorial is for Bitbucket **Cloud**, which is a totally different beast from the Bitbucket one hosts privately within an organization. If you want an issue tracker and wiki that integrate nicely with Bitbucket, you'll probably need to set up JIRA and Confluence.

Comment: @Quietust what's the difference between the two and can I migrate to cloud for free? We only have 2 repos so it wouldn't be a hassle if I had to do it manually

Comment: @Jason: I'd recommend checking out the Bitbucket website for more information.

Comment: @Quietust Apologies for not being clearer, I'm not hosting my own server, I'm using bitbucket's private repos on their website which afaik is the same as bitbucket cloud

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Nicolás was right, all I had to do was navigate to settings(something I couldn't do previously because I wasn't an admin on the repo) and [enable issue tracking there.](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/enable-an-issue-tracker-223216498.html)

From a repository,

1. click Settings.
2. Select Issue tracker from the left-hand tabs.
3. Check the option for either a Private issue tracker or a Public issue tracker.

The system saves your selection and the Issue Tracker item appears in the repository's menu bar.

Comment: doc on enabling the issue tracker: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/enable-an-issue-tracker-223216498.html

Comment: is this working also with bitbucket hosted privately?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer is correct for Bitbucket Cloud. There is no native support for issues in Bitbucket Server.